# SQL Query para sumar campos de distintas tablas

Tags: sql-server, sql

Alguien que me pueda ayudar con esta query. Tengo tres tablas con diferentes nombres.

```
Tabla Ejemplo1
fecha         campo1
2017-01-01    0.00
2017-01-01    7.00
2017-01-01    0.00
2017-01-01    1.00
2017-01-01    0.00
2017-01-02    1.00
2017-01-02    43.00
2017-01-02    1.00
2017-01-02    0.00
2017-01-02    0.00

Tabla Ejemplo2
fecha         campo2
2017-01-01    0.00
2017-01-01    5.00
2017-01-01    1.00
2017-01-01    3.00
2017-01-01    0.00
2017-01-02    1.00
2017-01-02    3.00
2017-01-02    2.00
2017-01-02    2.00
2017-01-02    0.00

Tabla Ejemplo3
fecha         campo3
2017-01-01    0.00
2017-01-01    5.00
2017-01-01    1.00
2017-01-01    3.00
2017-01-01    0.00
2017-01-02    1.00
2017-01-02    1.00
2017-01-02    0.00
2017-01-02    0.00
2017-01-02    0.00
```

Quiero sumar todos los campos con sus respectivos valores y luego unir las fechas en un bloque de fecha. Tal que así...

```
Tabla Final
fecha         campoTotal
2017-01-01    26.00
2017-01-02    55.00
```

He probado dos formas de hacerlo con consultas anidadas y con subquerys. Y de ninguna forma, he llegado a hacerlo. Alguien me puede echar un cable?

**Consultas**

```
SELECT [fecha],
       sum([campo1]) AS "campo1"
FROM Ejemplo1
WHERE fecha = '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY fecha

SELECT [fecha],
       sum([campo2]) AS "campo2"
FROM Ejemplo2
WHERE fecha = '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY fecha

SELECT [fecha],
       sum([campo3]) AS "campo3"
FROM Ejemplo3
WHERE fecha = '2017-01-01'
GROUP BY fecha
```

**Subquerys**

```
select fecha,sum(campo1) total
from
(
    select fecha,campo1
    from ejemplo1
    union all
    select fecha,campo2
    from ejemplo2
    union all
    select fecha,campo3
    from ejemplo3
) t
group by fecha
```

Comment: Tu segunda consulta parece correcta, que es lo que falla?

Comment: Falla que me trae valores muy raros de dios.

Comment: Oye este código es de MySql o de Sql Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he resuelto como bien deciais usando un INNER JOIN de las tablas.

```
SELECT conversions_1.fecha,
       ([columna 1] + [columna 2] + [columna 3] as conversiones_totales
       FROM
(SELECT [fecha],
       sum([campo1]) AS "columna 1"
FROM [dbo].[Ejemplo1]
GROUP BY fecha) as conversions_1

inner join

(SELECT [fecha],
       sum([campo2]) AS "columna 2"
FROM [dbo].[Ejemplo2]
GROUP BY fecha) as conversions_2

on conversions_1.fecha = conversions_2.fecha

inner join

(SELECT [fecha],
       sum([campo3]) AS "columna 3"
FROM [dbo].[Ejemplo3]
GROUP BY fecha) as conversions_3

on conversions_1.fecha = conversions_3.fecha

ORDER BY conversions_1.fecha
```

Comment: Recuerda que puedes dar tu respuesta como aceptada :)

Comment: En dos días tío, pero muchas gracias por recordármelo! :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un inner join, a mi me ha funcionado, suponiendo que en las 3 tablas vas a tener todas las fechas:

CONSULTA EDITADA

```
SELECT e1.fecha, (e1.campo1 + e2.campo2 + e3.campo3) from ejemplo1 e1 inner join ejemplo2 e2 on e1.fecha = e2.fecha inner join ejemplo3 e3 on e1.fecha = e3.fecha group by fecha;
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Con esto si me lo hace pero los valores son extraños @MarcPuig

`2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 61393.00`

Comment: @YoelMaciaDelgado He editado la consulta, se me escapo el sum() prueba con esta modificación a ver si te sirve

Comment: No, pero creo que tengo la solución.

Comment: @YoelMaciaDelgado Si llegaste la solución, publicala como respuesta y márcala como solución aceptada

Comment: Puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta en 2 días.